# Redux saga is not redirecting/routing for logout

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, router, redux-saga, react-router-redux

After successful login, I've a logout button in app.js onto which I click and must redirect to login page. I don't have any route for logout in index.js.Do we need it?

I've saga written the only which works fine the only problem is it doesn't route to /signIn from saga. Is it the right practice.
It never redirects via  any of the following routes,

**app.js**

```
logoutAction = () => {

  this.props.doLogoutAction();

  this.props.history.push('/sign') //I'venow implemented this and not routing via saga.-------------1>Please read updated
}
<button onClick = {this.handleLogot.bind(this)}> </button>
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  username: "",
  isLoggedIn: false
};

case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
  return { ...state,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    payload: action.payload.isLoggedIn
  };
case LOGIN_FAILED:

  return { ...state,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    payload: ''
  };
case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:

  return { ...state,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    payload: ''
  };
default:
  return state;
```

**saga.js**

** //here I put the logout success action to dispatch **

```
yield put({
  type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  payload: false
})


// history.push('/signIn')
//yield put(push('/signIn'))
//yield call(push,'/signIn')
this.props.history.push('/signIn')
```

only above two lines is the saga

I've tried all of those but then it doesn't work. Can anyone please lemme know where I'm going wrong.
Is there some other solution which we can implement? Has anyone worked onto logout/login functionality in your projects?

Update-1

after I place history push in logout it work I've removed from saga it works but due to reducer it redirecting to app.js. As in reducer the isLoggedIn is not updating where action login success id dispatched. It seems that I'm doing something wrong. Please lemme know where do I go wrong.

Update-2
Now the reducer is working for logout I can logout.But Now there's the problem I can't login as only action Login request then the login success saga is not called

LoginAction.js

```
      return{
                    type:LOGIN_ACTION,
                    payload:params

                }
```

Comment: Please include more code.

Comment: What does your `handleLogot` method looks like?

Comment: @win Please check I've updated the question

Comment: @BreakBB  Please check I've updated the question

Comment: Basically, you should fire the action, set `isLoggedIn` to false in redux store, then invoke `history.push()`

Comment: @Dane Please check the updates

Comment: There are still blackboxes for us so we can't see possible erros. `this.props.doLogoutAction()` simply fires some sort of "DO_LOGOUT" ID? How do you handle it in your saga.js then? Or do you now want to step back from saga and do basic redux actions?

Comment: @BreakBB I don't want stepback from saga i tired sicne three days but then saga routing doesn't work I'll go for  it if anyone lemme knows where i'm going wrong. since it was not working i opted for the other way out .But im not sure is it good practise? or something better can be done?

Comment: Okay, so please add all relevant lines from your saga.js file and `doLogoutAction` as well. Most likely you're handeling your actions wrong in saga.

Comment: @BreakBB all the code is in the question I've no more code. doLogoutAction PLz chec k the updates

Comment: So what about the creation of the redux-saga middleware? Do I understand you correctly that your saga actions are fired correctly and your store updates, but only the redirect does not work? In your saga.js it should be `yield put(push('/signIn'));` since I am not sure if the `history` is passed to saga. Any error messages?